# Analysing correlations between variables and points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, statistics, proximity

I am trying to determine the correlation between sinkholes and a number of different variables. My sourced data is as follows:

```
Sinkhole Database: 6460 points
Fault Lines: Line files
Surface Streams: Line files
Karst Landscape: Polygon file
Depth of soil to bedrock: DEM
```

I am using ArcMap 10.1

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to analyse the correlations between each variable and the points?

I have set up buffers around the river and fault lines, and have extremely simplistic counts at each of the boundaries, but would prefer something slightly more data rich!

Comment: Many people would start by using a GIS to create a *table* of tuples, one per point, containing attributes describing the geographic relationships between the sinkholes and the other features. Such relationships can include distance, bearing, presence/absence (as in karst landscape), and numerical value (as in depth of bedrock). That's merely the point of departure: now you abandon the GIS--it has done its job and typically is not the best tool for the next step--and move into exploratory data analysis and formal statistical analysis. But precisely how you do that depends on your objectives.